# [Boost::ext].SML: Segmentation fault in guard with Mingw64 GCC, debug build

Tags: c++, boost

### Code

```cpp
#include <sml.hpp>

namespace {

struct Event {
    bool pressed;
};

struct Guard1 {
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator()(const Event& e) const {
        return e.pressed;
    }
} guard1;

struct Guard2 {
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator()(const Event& e) const {
        return true;
    }
} guard2;

struct Guard3 {
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator()(const Event& e) const {
        return true;
    }
} guard3;

}// namespace

namespace sml = boost::sml;

struct Fsm {

    struct State {};

    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace boost::sml;

        return make_transition_table(
            // clang-format off
           *state<State> + event<Event>[guard1 && guard2 && guard3] = state<State>
            // clang-format on
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::sml::sm<Fsm> fsm{};
    fsm.process_event(Event{});
}
```

### Expected Behavior

No segmentation fault.

### Actual Behavior

Segmentation fault when accessing the `pressed` field in `Guard1`.

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

[image]

Event address is still **ok** in `front::transition::execute`:
[image]

But in `front::call::execute` it gets corrupted:
[image]

**If I remove one of the guard, it works fine.**

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

1. use gcc from MSYS2,  `gcc --version gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0`
2. build with `-g -std=gnu++20`
3. run

### Specifications

- Version: 1.1.4, 1.1.5
- Platform: Windows, GCC 12.1.0 (MSYS2 mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc)

Comment: What is the (exact) version of boost/sml? The include path is not expected with a regular Boost SML installation (expecting `#include <boost/sml.hpp>` instead)

Comment: I use : https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/releases/tag/v1.1.5.